# How do I trim a string from the left of a series of strings in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some user shares that I need to modify permissions on. The permissions part is working, but I'm trying to pull the username from the path to the folder. The folders are all in c:\user shares\j.smith format and I'm intending to use the username variable I get from the path in takeown and other commands.

My batch is so rusty I'm sure you heard the squeaking from your office.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set find=C:\user shares\
FOR /D %%p IN ("c:\user shares\*") DO (
    set str=%%p
    call set str=%%str:!find!=%%
    echo %str%
)
pause
```

My output for each folder is as follows.

```
(
echo c:\user shares\j.smith
 set uname=c:\user shares\j.smith
 echo
 set uname=%uname:!cut!=%
 echo
)
c:\user shares\j.smith
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
```

I need help getting through this basic issue so I can actually get to the string manipulation, where I'm sure I'll need help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("c:\user shares\*") DO (
    echo %%~nxp
)
```

may get you going (show the name and extension part of `%%p`)

but it's really unclear what you want to happen

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.